# Saving MongoDB cursor between HTTP requests in Flask

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, flask, pymongo

I am writing a webapp to display tweets from a MongoDB database using pymongo (regular pymongo) and flask.

The problem that I have is that when accessing paginated results, the search is being performed again and again, when all I really need to do is iterate over cursor.

```
Page 1: db.tweets.find({...})[0:20]
Page 2: db.tweets.find({...})[21:30]
Page 3: db.tweets.find({...})[31:40]
```

The call db.tweets.find({...}) is being called each time I change the page, ideally I want to do db.tweets.find({...}) once and store it into a variable called cursor, and then slice:

```
cursor = db.tweets.find({...})
Page 1: cursor[0:20]
Page 2: cursor[21:30], etc...
```

I thought about using sessions but cursors are not json serializable and I cannot store everything in memory. I was wondering if anyone knows how to store/persist a cursor between http requests so I don't have to keep calculating it each time, or maybe an alternative pagination method?

I do plan on making this webapp to have multiple concurrent users, so storing it globally probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  could sort the result and skip as you go

**My snippet:**

```
db.tweets.find().sort(("name", pymongo.ASCENDING)).limit(20).skip(20)

                                 or
#For Twenty pages to get twenty different tweets for each page
n=20
for i in range 10:
    db.tweets.find().sort(("name", pymongo.ASCENDING)).limit(20).skip((n*i))
```

Comment: I did some further research and found that skip & limit is not good for large datasets (http://blog.mongodirector.com/fast-paging-with-mongodb/) and my dataset is in the millions. I guess it really works for skipping pages, ie going to page 1 then 5 then 7.

then there is the range query and limit, but that is only good for sequential paging (page 1, 2, 3...)